# LogoutListener gives me an "InvalidArgumentException"

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony4, listeners

I am getting myself into symfony and actually I am stucked on authorization.

I would like to forward a user to a specific route, depending on its role. 
Oh, am using FOS Bundle.

services.yaml:

```
LogoutListener:
    class: App\Listeners\LogoutListener
    arguments:
        userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
```

security.yaml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        ....
        logout:
            handlers: [logoutlistener]
```

ListenerClass:

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface {

    protected $userManager;

    /**
     * LogoutListener constructor.
     * @param UserManagerInterface $userManager
     */
    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager){
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token) {
        die('user logged out');
    }
}
```

It always gives me:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Invalid service "LogoutListener": method "App\Listeners\LogoutListener::__construct()" has no argument type-hinted as "userManager". Check your service definition.
```

Any hint for me?
regards deAndro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony: Must be an instance of Twig\_Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898507/symfony-must-be-an-instance-of-twig-environment)

Answer (score 1):

Config has changed a bit with Symfony 4. This should do the trick:

**services.yaml**

```
services:
    App\Listeners\LogoutListener:
```

**security.yaml**

```
firewalls:
main:
    ....
    logout:
        handlers: [App\Listeners\LogoutListener]
```

**ListenerClass**

```
namespace App\Listeners;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface {

protected $userManager;

public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager = null)
{
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
}

public function logout(Request $Request, Response $Response, TokenInterface $Token) {

    die('user logged out');
    }
}
```

Comment: That helps, some Idea how I can get the route and user before the user pressed called the logout route?

Comment: Getting the user (in a controller) can be done with `$user = $this->getUser();`. Getting a route in twig can be done with `{{ app.request.get('_route') }}`.