# Symfony: Must be an instance of Twig_Environment

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to implement a password resset feature to an already made Symfony app. I think I am almost there ... But i am pretty new to Symfony and I am still searching my self arround ... I have a view that send a JSON post to a controller but it returns the following message:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener::__construct() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /home/***/public_html/intranet/var/cache/prod/ContainerJxqbmi7/getApp_Listener_ForgotPasswordService.php on line 8
```

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Event;
use CoopTilleuls\ForgotPasswordBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEvent;

class ForgotPasswordEventListener
{

    private $twig;
    private $mailer;
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $manager)
    {
        $this->templating = $twig;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->manager=$manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param ForgotPasswordEvent $event
     */
    public function onCreateToken(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
    {
        $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
        $user = $passwordToken->getUser();

        $swiftMessage = new \Swift_Message(
            'Reset of your password',
            $this->templating->render(
             'security/forgot-password.html.twig',
                [
                    'reset_password_url' => sprintf('http://www.example.com/forgot-password/%s', $passwordToken->getToken()),
                ]
            )
        );

        $swiftMessage->setFrom('no-reply@example.com');
        $swiftMessage->setTo($user->getEmail());
        $swiftMessage->setContentType('text/html');
        if (0 === $this->mailer->send($swiftMessage)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to send email');
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ForgotPasswordEvent $event
     */

    public function onUpdatePassword(ForgotPasswordEvent $event)
    {
        $passwordToken = $event->getPasswordToken();
        $user = $passwordToken->getUser();
        $user->setPlainPassword($event->getPassword());
        $this->manager->persist($user);
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
app.listener.forgot_password:
    class: AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener
    arguments:
        templating: "@twig"
        mailer:     "@mailer"
        manager:    "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
        - { name: templating.helper, alias: templating, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.create_token, method: onCreateToken}
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: coop_tilleuls_forgot_password.update_password, method: onUpdatePassword }
```

I am really don't know what I am doing wrong. Thx for your help!

Comment: Please take a look at your code one more time. In the example you have provided, the service is defined 2 times, with different configuration.

Comment: Your right! lol I probably tryed so many things that i did not notice the double service! But that gave me and other error. Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Invalid service "app.listener.forgot_password": method "AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener::__construct()" has no argument type-hinted as "templating". Check your service definition. in /home/quebecenreseau/public_html/intranet/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/ResolveNamedArgumentsPass.php:80 Stack trace: #0

Comment: The error you get is caused by your parameter naming defined in `services.yaml` Either rename `templating:` to `twig:` or use a dash `-` for each line, instead of naming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your service definition. I am not sure exactly what is causing this, but it seems that Symfony is rearranging the arguments. There are 2 ways to fix it. Either remove the keys for the arguments or fix them by properly using named properties:

```
app.listener.forgot_password:
    class: AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener
    arguments:
        - "@twig"
        - "@mailer"
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

or for the second approach:

```
app.listener.forgot_password:
    class: AppBundle\Event\ForgotPasswordEventListener
    arguments:
        $twig: "@twig"
        $mailer: "@mailer"
        $manager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

The important bit is the `$`-prefix and that the name matches the argument name in the constructor.